# Media query doesnt accept another one

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hey Guys i am trying to create a responsive layout for my website. I am using media queries to set the width in % of my 2 navigationbars : left and right.

I am kinda confused because the same syntax works simetimes and on some widths it doesn't work.

For Example:

```
@media (max-width:1000px)
{
  .left{width:50%}
  .right{width:50%}
}
```

works fine, but when i am doing this:

```
@media (max-width: 720px) 
{
  .left{width:25%}
  .right{width:25%}
}
```

it still takes the 1st statement ? The display width can be under 100 px and its still the first media query.

Comment: That's right, 100px is still less than 1000px. So you have two media queries that are both true.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a specific example this should work but you should be aware that the *order* of the media queries is important.

Correct Order (when using max-width:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {
    .left {
        width:50%;
    }
    .right {
        width:50%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .left {
        width:25%;
    }
    .right {
        width:25%;
    }
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fp1qv32t/1/)

Incorrect Order (when using max-width): [**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fp1qv32t/2/)

Comment: I can't help but notice that your order is the same as the OP's.

Comment: I did say that it should work BUT it's not clear that he's actually using *both* at the same time and, if so, in what order.

Comment: Hm... I would have answered that it's best to explicitly write `(min-width: 721px) and (max-width: 1000px)` to avoid ambiguity, but you're right that there may be other things at play. I mean, your fiddle does work, so the OP has not provided all the information there is.

Comment: i changed the order and added ,,screen and" but it still doesn't work ? your fiddle doesn't work too.

Comment: Depends on which demo you are looking at...the first one absolutely *does* work...the second obviously will not.

Comment: If you have a demo that doesn't work...perhaps you need to [edit] that into your question.

Comment: I tried both fiddles on chromes device mode. Both doesn't work. I tried the same without the device mode and it worked. LOL my code just works not on device mode but i guess the device mode is more important then switching the browser sice isn't it ?

Comment: If the "device mode" is emulating a device with a fixed screen size (say 800px wide) then resizing the window has no effect. Or what do you mean by "more important"?

Comment: the responsive view is for devices like tablets or mobile  phones not for user who switch their browser window, so the device monitor view is the important view or isnt it ?